How can I display the Query name as a column when I actually run the query?
I run a bunch of queries that check for inconsistencies in our data set.  I literally have hundreds of these queries and when one of them has a result I forward it as an excel file to the appropriate colleague.  I'd like to include the actual name of the query as a field in the grid view that I used to create the query.  For example, if the query is named "Test 1961", I'd like to create a column inside the query labeled "Query Name" that would then, actually display "Test 1961" in a column labeled "Query_Name" in the results table.  I searched google and it said the entering """ would generate the query name. I tried that suggestion and just get an error message.
I entered """ and also just " and also '"'but it did not display the name of the query being run.

select 'Test 1961' as Query_Name, your_query_columns from ...?

I'm sorry I don't understand your response.  I'm trying to get Access to automatically enter the name of the query into the gridview. I know that I could simply create a text field and manually enter the name of the query, but if the query name changes, then my "manual" entry will not match the actual name of the query.  Does that help?

Why would query name change?

The suggested idea here is to include the query name as a column. It would of course be manually entered, and done by hand.  However, if you going make a copy of a query, THEN YOU ARE going to modify the query, right? So, then modify the column name to the new query name while you doing this. So, yes, this idea is not automatic, but just make it a simple habit when you copy a query.

To HansUp. I can not provide the link. Sorry.  I simple went into Google and typed "ms access how to create field that show the query name" and I swear it said to enter " to display the query name. But I just tried rerunning the search and it gives a different result. Maybe it's because I "thumbs down" the earlier result?

To June7: The query names change because we create dozens of queries to catch data integrity issues. We have number them and sometimes it makes sense to group them and renumber.  This maynot be a best practice, but we're not database experts, just using access as a tool.

To Albert D. Kallal.  I hear you and your suggestion works until someone forgets to follow the directions. This happens. That's why we want to have a column that displays the quesry name.

Create a function to retrieve the name of the (first) opened query:
Public Function CurrentQueryName() As String

    Dim Query       As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim QueryName   As String
    
    For Each Query In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
        If SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acQuery, Query.Name) > 0 Then
            QueryName = Query.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    CurrentQueryName = QueryName
    
End Function

Then include that function in your relevant queries:
SELECT 
    CurrentQueryName() AS SourceQuery, 
    <other fields>
FROM
    <tables>

Now you can rename or copy your queries at will and still have the actual query name returned when a query is opened.
Of course, it will only run as expected if no other queries are open.

Gustav.  Thanks. I haven't tried your query, yet. I'll give it a go as soon as I can.  The problem is though, I can't guarantee this will be the first opened query.  We have a macro that opens dozens of these queries sequentially, in a specific order. I need the respective query name to show up in each query that is opened.

OK, too bad. That my simple function cannot handle. Then, I guess, you are back to Albert's method to manually write in the query name.
